# Is there any battles like Gilbert on the Glorious in Trails from Zero?

Tags: trails-from-zero

I'm debating what difficulty to play *Trails from Zero*. i don't mind a challenge but my goal for my first run is to max DP as much as possible to get the top rank and get the full bonus from my save import when i go to play *Trails from Azure*.

the reason for this debate is that in *Trails in the Sky SC* there was an annoying fight on the Glorious against Gilbert and 4 Jaegers where to get all the BP, this fight had to be won in so many turns (not just survive)

quick skimming [this FAQ](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/psp/995652-eiyuu-densetsu-zero-no-kiseki/faqs/78210/chapter-2-golden-sun-silver-moon) for what bonus DP there is i see on one page

> Testaments Training
>
> ...
>
> - Win all 3 fights (+5DP)

[on this page](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/psp/995652-eiyuu-densetsu-zero-no-kiseki/faqs/78210/chapter-3-crossbell-anniversary-festival)

> Boss: Blade Fang x4
>
> ...
>
> - Win the fight (+3DP)

and [on this page](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/psp/995652-eiyuu-densetsu-zero-no-kiseki/faqs/78210/final-chapter-crossbells-longest-day) a few *"(Win for +1DP)"*

trying to remain plot spoiler free i don't know if any of these are timed fights like the fight against Gilbert in *Trails in the Sky SC* where to "Win" is to win the battle before it auto ends. if they are like it then turning playing on an easier difficulty would make them less painful but if they aren't i can play defensive (did a boss battle in Digital Devil Saga where i was on deference for like 10-15 minutes)

So is there any battles in *Trails from Zero* like Gilbert on the Glorious in *Trails from Zero* where 1 get Bonus DP for winning the battle over just surviving # Turns?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing exactly like it, but there are fights that are pretty challenging on a first playthrough. There's a fight where only Lloyd participated. There are a couple fights throughout the game where NPCs can't be hit for max DP.

Comment: when you say *"There's a fight where only Lloyd participated"*, i take it that there's no Bonus DP involved?

Comment: Sorry for not responding. This isn't a place I normally check! If you beat the battle in 32 turns or less, you get +3 DP. If you don't die, but don't beat it in that turn limit, you get +1 DP.